# Cascading Dropdown is not working in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have two fields **"CustomerName"** and **"ContactPerson"** in my view. if i select the **CustomerName** the value which is depend to **CustomerName** is need to store in **ContactPeson** dropdown. As per below code it fetch the data from Db and store in both dropdowns and also if i select the **"CustomerName"** the related **"ContactPerson"** is automatically store or display in  **ContactPerson** Dropdown. All are working fine. But the issue is if i select the value in dropdowns and try to save it in Db its not saving the value. The value will be null for both fields. I donno where i did mistake. Any one give solution for this problem.

Advance Thanks..

My view
[CascadingDropDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6dgo.jpg)

**My ViewModel**

```
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerContactID { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
```

**My View**

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName , new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCustomer", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @style = "width:250px;" })
</div>
</div>



 <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">

                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCustomerContact", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @style = "width:250px;" })
            </div></div>
```

**j-query code**

```
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#dropdownCustomer').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#dropdownCustomer').change(function () {

        $('#dropdownCustomerContact').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/VisitorsForm/GetContactPersobByCustomerId",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { CustomerID: $('#dropdownCustomer').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownCustomerContact').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
    ViewBag.CustomerContactID = new SelectList(db.CustomerContacts, "CustomerContactID", "ContactReference");

    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName");
        return View();
    }

 public JsonResult GetCustomers()
    {
        return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
 public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);


        var customercontacts = from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a;

        return Json(customercontacts);
    }

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VisitorsViewModel visitorviewmodel)
    {

   ViewBag.CustomerContactID = new SelectList(db.CustomerContacts, "CustomerContactID", "ContactReference",visitorviewmodel .CustomerContactID );

ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName",visitorviewmodel .CustomerID );

  var VisitorsViewObj = new VisitorsForm()
        {
  CustomerID = visitorviewmodel.CustomerID,
  CustomerContactID = visitorviewmodel.CustomerContactID
   };
```

Comment: Your naming your `<select>` elements `dropdownCustomer` and `dropdownCustomerContact` respectively. Your model does not contain any proeprties with those names - use `CustomerID` and `CustomerContactID` assuming those are the properties you want to bind to (although its unclear what the purpose of the other 2 properties are)

Comment: i have property for customerID and CustomerContactID

Comment: And you have create 2 `ViewBag` properties which you never use, and given them the same name as the model properties so even if you did use them, it would not work. And do not return collections of  `Customers` and `CustomerContacts ` in you JsonResult method - return a collection of anonymous objects containing only the properties your need to generate the options.

Comment: Yes, I know you have those properties. If you want to bind to them, the the name of the dropdownlists need to match - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerID, new SelectList(....`

Comment: I recommend you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: now i have to match the name of the DD like CustomerID??

Comment: Yes of course. When you submit the form, your current code is sending `dropdownCustomer=someValue&dropdownCustomerContact=anotherValue` - how could that possibly be matched to your model properties :)

Comment: ok stephen let i have a try as per you said

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName , new { @class = "control-  label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @style = "width:250px;" })
                   </div>
                   </div>


   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

        </div> </div>


   $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#CustomerID').change(function () {

        $('#CustomerContactID').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/VisitorsForm/GetContactPersobByCustomerId",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```